# How to render image in remote docker and dispaly the pictur in local?

Tags: docker

I try to run simple docker with only X11 to make it run xeyes. It works
on the local machine, but, if i run the docker on remote machine i get
the "cannot open display"

Running the docker by the following commands:

```
xhost +
docker run -it --rm  -e DISPLAY  -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix  uuddii/helox11
```

In remote machine, i login by ssh -Y and then one of the following three commands:

```
docker run -it --rm  -e DISPLAY  -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix  uuddii/helox11

docker run -it --rm  -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY  -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix  uuddii/helox11

docker run -it --rm  -e DISPLAY=myHost:0  -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix  uuddii/helox11
```

Any idea how to render image in remote docker and display the output?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12755/how-to-forward-x-over-ssh-to-run-graphics-applications-remotely

Comment: thanks erik258.  when i run xeyes from remote it works, it doesnt work if i run it by the docker.    regarding the xhost it is for debug only